# Why is this recursive function creating an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, recursion, infinite-loop

The following code results in an infinite loop. The value of a does not seem to be going lower than 1. Please help.

```
int main()
{
    init(4);
    return 0;
}
void init(int a)
{
    int j;      
    cout<<"After declaring: "<<j;
    j = a;
    cout<<"After initializing: "<<j;
    a--;
    while(a>0)
    {   
        init(a);    
    }   
}
```

Comment: `a` never changes value in the loop, and the recursive call doesn't do anything to modify it in the original scope. You may mean to remove the loop or pass the int by reference or return it from the recursive call.

Comment: Try to read about the different ways of passing parameters to functions and the differences between them (e.g. passing by value vs. passing by reference/pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are accessing an uninitialized variable. This introduces undefined behaviour into your program; I'd remove this section.

Second, your `while`-loop runs as long as `a > 0`, but in the body of the loop, the value of `a` is never changed. Note that when calling `init`, parameter `a` is passed by value, i.e. the value of `a` is copied; Each instance of `init` will get it's own `a`, and it will never change the value of the caller's `a`.

Recursive functions usually are used instead of a loop. Nevertheless, you need an "anchor" to tell the recursion where to stop:

```
void init(int a)
{
    int j = a;
    cout<<"After initializing: " << j;
    if (a>0) {
       init (a-1);
    }  
}
```